# c++: circular buffer with integer indices as iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, circular-buffer

I'm writing a C++ application where I need a cache of the last *n* messages that have arrived. And I need a way to get the index of the last message stored so that I can later on figure out all messages that have arrived afterwards. As this index has to be transported forward and back over HTTP, it should be easy representable and checkable as it becomes potentially unsafe user content.

So far I was thinking of using the `boost::circular_buffer`. But I couldn't find a way to figure out the index of the latest entry except the iterator.

So is there a way to some how (efficiently) get an integer index?
Or is there a way to encode and decode the iterator into a string that's savely validateable?
Or perhaps even a totally different way that I didn't think of yet?

(Anything up to C++11 is allowed; STL/stdlib and Boost highly preferred)

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/

Comment: Is there some reason it must be restricted to a set number n? A `std::deque` sounds like a good fit here, minus the set size.

Comment: @Griwes I concur, but its often used in vernacular due to the prevailing usage *before* the standard. It is the reason you don't  put an adhesive bandage on a cut; you use a damn Band-Aid. I use "standard library", "std lib", "stdlib" whenever I can, but don't expect that usage to take hold universally anytime soon. In the meantime, settle back and enjoy a refreshing glass of flavored drink mix, or as we call it on the four corners of this planet, Kool-Aid.

Comment: To get indexes, you simply need to subtract or use `std::distance` (if that is what you are looking for).

Comment: Is this is a circular buffer with a fixed number of messages?  If so, how about using a std::vector?

Comment: @JesseGood, a distance calculation won't help unless you have a fixed reference that you can use to reconstitute the iterator.

Comment: `std::distance` sounded very good for me. But subtracting (or using `distance`) `cb.begin()` of the unused `cb` from the current `cb.begin()` was allways giving me same result once the `cb` was full and new messages were overwriting the old ones :(

Comment: @Yuushi, how could I get the index numer (or similar) with a `std::deque`? It's non constant size wouldn't be a problem for me but it also wouldn't give me any advantages over `boost::circular_buffer`, would it?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about erasing items from the buffer until they get overwritten by new data, this becomes almost trivial to implement with a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<item> buffer;
buffer.reserve(BUFFER_SIZE);
int next_slot = 0;

// to insert:
if (next_slot >= buffer.size())
    buffer.push_back(new_item);
else
    buffer[next_slot] = new_item;
++next_slot;
if (next_slot >= BUFFER_SIZE)
    next_slot = 0;
```

Comment: You are right, the good ol' `std::vector` with some custom logic should do the trick nicely.

Comment: The call to reserve will only set the capacity, not the size. I think you want to 'resize' there, which can be replaced with the constructor call that takes the size as the first parameter.

Comment: @dma notice that it uses `push_back` if the data is to be written past the current size. `reserve` is only used as an aid to efficiency in this case and could be dropped entirely.

Comment: @MarkRansom right you are. If you used resize, then you wouldn't need the size check at all. You can just insert into 'next_slot' and increment/mod. Of course, accessing then becomes trickier as you have to deal with a potentially partially filled buffer.